# google font import doesn't work on linux

Tags: css, linux, macos

I'm currently finishing up a website but I have a weird problem. I have a font imported from Google, in my CSS file.

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab);
```

Then I just do a normal font-family call on the body tag like this.

```
body{
    font-family:'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

It works fine in Chrome, Firefox, Exploder, Safari, Opera on Windows and whatever else I've been able to try it on.

I was at school yesterday between classes working on it, the computers in the lab are all Linux machines, I opened up the website with Firefox on Linux and the font didn't load on any of them. It defaulted to the sans-serif.

I also just checked on Safari on my Mac at work and it doesn't load there either. It defaults to sans-serif.

Is this a problem with the font file types on Google and would I have to go import the eof and ttf and all those in order to fix this? or is it something else?

Comment: do you see the font on google page?
https://www.google.com/fonts#QuickUsePlace:quickUse/Family:Josefin+Slab

Comment: yes I did use that font.

Comment: can you see it clearly when you check font page on Linux?

Comment: Sorry i didn't get a good look at the font, mine was sans-serif version.

Comment: I can't answer that right now either i'll try mac though.

Comment: mac doesn't show sans.

Comment: so I think you should convert font to work on mac. OTF can work on both linux and window

Comment: That is what I did and it works now.

Comment: Jay suggested fontsquirrel and it works on mac now, i'll have to test linux when I get home

Comment: good luck :) hope it'll work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest uploading the font to http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ using the webfont generator.

This will then give you the fontface css and also different font file types for cross browser compatability.

Comment: Yeah I know about that I was going to go there if I had to. But i'm not sure if its something with google not having the other file types or something else.

Comment: Its most likely due the fact it needs different font types yes. Hope it works out for you :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are importing Josefin Slab and are calling `Josefin Sans`.

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab);

body{
    font-family:'Josefin Slab', sans-serif;
}
```

That should work.

Comment: I guess they got mixed up somehow I copied the import they gave me from sans and it must have given me the other.